# URL problems with htaccess and CMS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've developed my own CMS in PHP and now I'd like to make it SEO-Friendly, but I'm having some problems.

Most of the pages of the website are accessible from a id, like:

```
www.example.com/?id=alphanumericId123
www.example.com/?id=main
```

and so on, and I'd like to rewrite the URL of this pages:

```
www.example.com/aplhanumericId/
www.example.com/main/
```

I have wrote this rewrite rule, and it works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

but It cannot work for those few pages that are accessible by a static file or just for the scripts.
Isn't there a way to make some exceptions? Like:

```
if the requested file exsist {
    if it is protected {
        display error 403
    } else {
        display file
} } else {
    rewrite rule
}
```

Comment: Ack, what a waste. Almost finished my answer. Here it goes: Doesn't really matter.

As long as it's indeed a *Controller* - a little servant between an HTTP request and a Model - it doesn't really matter how this request to the Model is made. Once you'd decide to move the Model to the separate server, you can simply change the calling method as well. 

However, for the moment I wouldn't bother with making an API. Instead I would focus on the database infrastructure. It's a database that makes all the payload. Hence consider using the master/slave replication and allow the Model to choose

Comment: Oh sorry! I've moved the question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/423814/

Comment: What do you mean with master/slave replication and choosing?

Comment: I mean writes are going to the master and reads are distributed between slaves.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Got it, I just took a quick read about that, interesting. If a class handles both reads and writes, should I split it into two classes or just construct it with two database connections?

Comment: No need to split, just accept two connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rewrite paths to existing files and directories:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Exclude existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Exclude existing directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Also note that your rule will not allow you alphanumeric id's as you are excluding numbers.

Alternatives would be:

```
...
# No forward slash
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

or

```
...
# Only a selection of characters including - and _
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: @yessure And it works when you comment-out these 2 conditions and the  rule?

Comment: No, I just made a mistake, sorry. The first condition you have wroted works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following before your RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Basically it checks if it's not a file, and not a directory.